# What is Bonjour and why should I use it over?

Tags: windows, vb.net, bonjour

What are the advantages of using Bonjour in a program (vb.net), is it even possible? Couldn't I get the same end result using just what I program?

Comment: FYI: http://craz.net/programs/ZeroconfNetServices/

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write it yourself. But:

- It would take a lot of time and effort
- You would need to test it
- You would need to maintain it

Using a standard tested library generally results in a cheaper and more robust solution.

http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html